# Как отключить фильтрация поиска?

Tags: php, yii

```
if(count(Yii::app()->request->getParam('RefMahala',['name_'.Yii::app()->language])
  ['name_'.Yii::app()->language])>0 || intval(Yii::app()->request->getParam('RefMahala',
  ['district_id'=>null])['district_id']) > 0 ){
}
```

В этом куске кода идет проверка на пустые полученные данные, если они пусты то нужно отключить поиск. Если этого не сделать он возвращает данные предыдущего. Вообще как отключить поиск ? Yii1

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'fixedHeader' => true,
    'headerOffset' => 30,
    'id' => 'analiz-create-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    //'filter' => $model,
    'filter'=>false,
```

Вы про это? Или про это:

```
<?php //echo CHtml::link('Расширенный поиск', '#', array('class' => 'search-button btn')); ?>
```

a еще можно так

```
<style>
.items tr.filters{ display: none;}
</style>
```